# How to change font size in ttk.Button?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, ttk

This is my problem, I was building an interface for a program, but for needs of the bosses, the font must be larger.
I have changed the font size of every widget without any problem, but with the ttk.Buttons, I was unable to change it...
I was reading that ttk.Button doesn't support the font attribute, but tk.Button supports it.
I tried with tk.Button and it works, but I don't like the graphic style of this tk.Button...

Is there any way to change the font style and size of a ttk.Button, or changed the graphic style of the tk.Button to make similar to the ttk?

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to use [styles](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) to customize `ttk` widgets.

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('my.TButton', font=('Helvetica', 12))
b = ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Press me', style='my.TButton',
command=foo)
```

Comment: Does `font` take any other arguments? For example `font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold', 'justify'))`. Is argument order important?

Comment: @Siemkowski The expression `(…, …, …)` is a __tuple__. In this case the font name is required, while the size and style are optional. Yes, the order is important, since there are no names to identify the values.

Answer (score 5):

The Above answer is correct and you can change the style for all of ttk widgets(for example font) you can change the root's style whose name is '.':

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('.', font=('Helvetica', 12))
```

After that, all of your ttk widgets's uses 'Helvetica' font in size '12'.
The answer, derived from "https://tkdocs.com/shipman/ttk-style-layer.html"

Answer (score 0):

adding more :

```
....

from tkinter.font import BOLD, Font 

.....

root = tkinter.Tk()

fontz = Font(root , family = 'Ubuntu',  size = 12 , weight = BOLD , underline = 1)

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('.', font=fontz)



.....
.....
.....
.....

#then you can use :
fontz['size'] = 60



.....
root.mainloop()
```