# Adding a check next to the selected item in tkinter OptionMenu

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, optionmenu, tkinter.optionmenu

How could I add a check sign next to the currently selected item (or highlight it) in a OptionMenu in a tkinter GUI? The idea is that when I click again to select another item, I can see easily which one is selected (similar to the following picture)

[image]

I just added a new example:

```py
from tkinter import *

OptionList = [
"Aries",
"Taurus",
"Gemini",
"Cancer"
] 

app = Tk()

app.geometry('100x200')

variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set(OptionList[0])

opt = OptionMenu(app, variable, *OptionList)
opt.config(width=90, font=('Helvetica', 12))
opt.pack(side="top")


labelTest = Label(text="", font=('Helvetica', 12), fg='red')
labelTest.pack(side="top")

def callback(*args):
    labelTest.configure(text="The selected item is {}".format(variable.get()))

variable.trace("w", callback)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are `Checkbutton` with tkinter, that works like checkboxes.

Comment: I know, can I bind that to an OptionMenu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter drop down list of check-boxes/combo-boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781047/tkinter-drop-down-list-of-check-boxes-combo-boxes)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i am looking something more similar to the picture i added in the question

Comment: @Adrian I'm sorry, just use the ttk version of it.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54263409/13629335

Comment: Ive added a detailed answer

Comment: thank you, i already decided to do that since i did not find a way on tk

Comment: Yes you can get the similar result using `tk.OptionMenu`.  Added answer for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ttk` widgets for this modern looking style, try saying something like:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
....
     #arguments  -  master  variable     default      *values
opt = ttk.Optionmenu(app, variable, OptionList[0], *OptionList)
```

The effect given by this is pretty similar or maybe identical to what your trying to achieve.

You might notice an additional third positional argument here, it is actually `default=OptionList[0]` argument specified here(specific to just `ttk.Optionmenu`), it is just the default value that the optionmenu will display, ignoring this might lead to some bugs in the looks of optionmenu, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406250/optionmenu-in-tkinter-does-not-work-properly-when-ttkthemes-is-used).

And also keep in mind, it does not have a `font` option too. To overcome this, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068708/how-to-change-font-size-in-ttk-button) out

Hope this was of some help to you, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can get similar effect using `tk.OptionMenu`:

```py
from tkinter import *

OptionList = [
"Aries",
"Taurus",
"Gemini",
"Cancer"
] 

app = Tk()

app.geometry('300x200')

variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set(OptionList[0])

opt = OptionMenu(app, variable, None) # need to supply at least one menu item
opt.config(width=90, font=('Helvetica', 12))
opt.pack(side="top")

# populate the menu items
menu = opt['menu']
menu.delete(0) # remove the None item
for item in OptionList:
    menu.add_radiobutton(label=item, variable=variable)

labelTest = Label(text="", font=('Helvetica', 12), fg='red')
labelTest.pack(side="top")

def callback(*args):
    labelTest.configure(text="The selected item is {}".format(variable.get()))

variable.trace("w", callback)

app.mainloop()
```